# Using dotcmis in Windows Store app not working

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, alfresco, cmis, dotcmis

I want to use dotcmis in my Windows store app. I downloaded the dotcmis-0.6 and added a reference from my Windows app project. While building, it is giving me an error as this :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v12.0\8.1\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(327,9): Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Cannot find type System.ApplicationException in module mscorlib.dll.
```

Looks like it is something to do with the version compatibility of dotcmis and Windows store app.

How can I use dotcmis in Windows Store App

Comment: Do you perhaps need to include whatever library provides `System.ApplicationException` into your build?

Comment: `System.ApplicationException` is part of mscorlib. I think the problem is that DotCMIS is a general .NET library, not a WinRT library or a Portable Class Library and as such can't be used directly in a windows store app.

Comment: As @Tim mention, you will likely have to try and get the DotCMIS source, change the target to a Windows Store Class Library, fix any issues that present themselves, and recompile.

Comment: Hi Nate and Tim,

Could you please explain what do you mean by changing the target ?
I have downloaded the source. Is it that I create an Windows class library project and copy the code?